# what factors can cause major drop in ranking after site migration?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, ranking

My client has implemented the changes below:

- website platform
- URL path
- structure (adding some subfolders)
- removing www from the URL
- content (meta tags)

They have lost theirs ranking even for branded keywords from 1 to nothing.but they haven't lost traffic.
I guess these might be the problems:
 - I checked the previous URLs' search console accounts and some of the uRLs are still valid.
 - There are lots of redirect chains
 - some of the new meta tags focus on the same keyword
 - There have been lots of unnecessary changes in the URLs like adding a hyphen. so there are lots of unnecessary redirections as well.
 - Also it is a dental services website. I've heard that Google new algorithms my have affected it as well.

That would be great if you let me if I am right or not.
Also should I exclude all the redirected links in the previous search console accounts?

Comment: Everything you mentioned can impact rankings. Either the platform or the URL changes are probably the highest-impact items. If at all possible, fix redirect chains and make sure everything is properly 301'ing to the correct deep link, as quickly as possible, to recover some of the lost traffic. You should also set a preferred subdomain in Search Console to help clue Google in to the non-www change, or possibly consider adding www back in since presumably all backlinks include it. Not sure what you mean by "exclude" redirected links, or why there are "previous" search console accounts?

Comment: Thanks for your answer:)
in the new Google search console under coverage you can see all the excluded links which include redirected pages as well. So I assume you can mention all the redirected pages in the previous version of sitemap to help google find out which pages have been redirected and what is the target URL. There are a search console account for each variation of the website (http://, https://, www, non www, etc).